# Relation OneToOne with symfony3/doctrine

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine

I try to create a OneToOne relation with inheritance :

```
abstract class A { }
class A1 extends A { }
class A2 extends A { }

class F {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne( ? )
     */
    private $object; // Could be of type A1 or A2
}
```

I would like to do this :

```
$f = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:F')->findExample();
$object = $f->getObject(); // Return instance of A1 or A2
```

What annotations should be used?

Comment: why do you not use two objects ? `private objectA1` for class A1 and `private objectA2`  for class A2 ?

Comment: i'm looking for a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unidirectional relation, which means that you only need an F entity containing an A entity then you can use an unidirectional relation:

```
class F {

    /**
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="A")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_a", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
      private $a_object;
}
```

Note that the relation was established with A, that means that the object could be of any of A1 or A2.  If you need a bidirectional , them you should place an annotation in A too:

```
class A {

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="F", mappedBy="a_object")
     **/
    private $f_object;
}
```

Also note that you can inverse both annotations between F and A, depending of which you consider as the main side. Check this [links](http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) and this [links](http://doctrine2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) for more information.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Exact, but A has to be an entity too. He should use a table inheritance.

Comment: Yes, A should be an Entity, but defined as abstract, which means that object must be of A1 or A2. I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: You can only rely on a related object if the ID column is shared between A1 and A2 (Class Table Inheritance or Single Table Inheritance).

Comment: Otherwise doctrine don't know if it should find the related entity in A1 or in A2.